# How to get a list of video games names in Freebase

Tags: api, freebase

What is the best way to get a list of the names of all video games in Freebase? Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

The Freebase topic type for game is `cvg/computer_videogame` :
http://www.freebase.com/cvg/computer_videogame?schema=

So you can list video games like this: https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&filter=%28any+type%3A%2Fcvg%2Fcomputer_videogame%29

Comment: Thanks but this lists only a few games. How can I get all video games in FreeBase?

Comment: By default freebase returns 20 results. Use &limit=100 in your query to retrieve more, e.g. a 100. You can use combination of limit and cursor for pagination if your single request get too big.

Comment: How can i get a list of video games and their developers only?